# why android studio app indexing test showing network error

Tags: android

I am doing app indexing in my application i have some doubts that i described below,

1. android studio --> run --> edit configuration --> general tab --> launch option drop down --> choosed URL and copy paste my URL `http://<example.com>/`--> run app here am not getting any errors infact in app index log am getting the logs

i have declared my manifest file like this,

```
 <activity android:name=".sample.activity.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="www.example.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/MYPREFIX"
                android:scheme="http"
                />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and i written in onStart method in java file , before that i have declared and initiated GoogleApiClient class in onCreate() like this

```
client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

 @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    client.connect();
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW,
            "MainPage",
            Uri.parse("`http://www.example.com/`"),
            Uri.parse("`android-app://package/http/www.example.com/prefix/`")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
}
```

then in onStop method i did like this

```
 @Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW,
            "MainPage",Uri.parse("`http://www.example.com/`"),

            Uri.parse("`android-app://package/http/www.example.com/prefix/`")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);

    client.disconnect();
}
```

there is no error in above code , but when am using the URL for app indexing test am getting error in android stuio, i tested in this way

android studio --> tools --> android --> Google App Indexing Test --> new window open --> in URL section i gave `http://www.example.com/ (or) http://www.example.com/prefix/` both are not working am getting error like this

**Network error, please try later.
    1. Google cannot index this page using Google bot crawling.
    2.  Google cannot index this page using the App Indexing API. **

in google app --> setting --> phone search --> i can see my app is checked by default.

then i cheked in file --> other settings --> default setting --> inspection code --> missing support for google app indexing and missing support for google app indexing api but the screenshot will tell you what i am getting pls see that below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmmwq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpJ0b.png)
But since am can not see the app index in chrome in android device if am search related to my app, where i missed anything or shall i release a beta version ?? what i want to do?? please tell me

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to clear something here for Google AppIndexing.For clear basics lets divide it into two parts

**Support HTTP URLs**
For this you just need to declare applinks in your manifest file on the basis of your URL as you have mentioned above.

to test this you need to go to Android studio>Build>Edit Configuration >Launch options>select **URL**>*then type in your Url here* >Apply and test.

This is different from GoogleAppIdexing API.Even if you do not include App indexing Api. This will work.

**Second portion of App Indexing is :- Adding AppIndexing API** 
In which we have to include code in our activities onCreate() and onStop() method.

**UPDATED:**
1.Choose File > Other Settings > Default Settings > Editor > Inspections > Android Lint.
2.Uncheck Incorrect usage of app link for Google App Indexing and Missing support for Google App Indexing.
[image]
3.Manually run syntax checking by selecting Analyze > Inspect Code from the application or right-click menu.

Comment: Do you have associated website with your app??

Comment: ofcourse, by using this URL https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en i was associate my app .. is this correct site know ??

Comment: Did you added assetlinks.json file on your server's .well-known directory.This how i associated my app with website.

Comment: check server’s robot.txt file and allow crawling for your content, check this link https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/getting_started

Comment: yes i did it like this

Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap-latest.xml
Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap_index.xml
Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap_news.xml

is there any other way to do ?? will pls explain me clearly.. thanks

Comment: That is good if you have mentioned your web pages in your sitemap.So that google can crawl these pages.But first you need to allow Google to look for your sitemap too,that is why I asked you to check robot.txt file.This is the example of robot.txt file https://qa.fame.live/robots.txt I have disabled crawling for this evironment.For  other crawl errors you can go to Search Console https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6178088?hl=en&rd=1&authuser=1

Comment: How to use search Console,check here crawl status,.....https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/measure?authuser=1

Comment: yes i referred this recipe app example, they are used content-provider and some callback methods, but i am not using any callback methods and content-provider, i am just using only googleapiclient and onStart() and onStop methods.. but while am using this example i can index the content in google search but if i am using my app i can not indexing in google search..

Comment: also this is my robots.txt contents pls refer it
Disallow: /test/
Disallow: /names/
Disallow: /*titles-index*.html
Disallow: /*title-index*.html
Disallow: /*ntitle--index*.html
Disallow: /*title--index*.html
Disallow: /*title--index*.html
Disallow: /*title--index*.html
Disallow: /scripts/
Disallow: /*?content_id=*
Disallow: /*?referer=*
Disallow: /fb_domainname_prefix/
User-agent: agentname-Google
Disallow:
Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap-latest.xml
Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap_index.xml
Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap_prefix.xml

Comment: User-agent: * Disallow: /test/  Disallow: /names/ Disallow: /*titles-index*.html Disallow: /*title-index*.html Disallow: /*ntitle--index*.html Disallow: /*title--index*.html Disallow: /*title--index*.html Disallow: /*title--index*.html Disallow: /scripts/ Disallow: /*?content_id=* Disallow: /*?referer=* Disallow: /fb_domainname_prefix/ Sitemap: example.com/sitemap-latest.xml Sitemap: example.com/sitemap_index.xml Sitemap: example.com/sitemap_prefix.xml  Make these changes an use Search console for further errors.Google take some time time to index your pages it might take 2 to 3 days to index.

Comment: yeah we addded long back and we didn't get any crawl errors in our google account.. since i am trying to get app indexing of my app but i can not ... any guess ??

Comment: okay Run your App and go to those screen where you have written code using app Indexing API.remember the title you have given.Then close your App and search that title in your Phone's GoogleSearchBar.Is it showing link to your App with the same Title????

Comment: no i am not able to see.. i am using my mobile chrome .. i searched the particular content but its not showing ..

Answer (score -1):

Adding AppIndexing API indexes your content and used in Auto completions in Google search Bar.Lets take example of inShorts Application for each page there is a headline and small description.After reading 2 or 3 headlines,close the application and move to google searchBar.
[image]
Try entering headline you just went through,you will get App page suggestion with that Headline as Title.This is different from App suggestions you get while searching for Apps.This happens because you have written AppIndexing API code for this particular page and title is same as you have initialized in onCreate.
[image]